# jQuery ajax success function not working in wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am having an issue with jQuery in wordpress. The jQuery ajax success function is not displaying nor getting response. A response is gotten from the server, but success function isn't getting response.

This is my code. Thanks.

<--jQuery-->

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $("#date").change(function(event) {
    var val1= document.getElementById('val1').value;
    var val2= document.getElementById('val2').value;
    var val3= document.getElementById('val3').value;

            $.ajax({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost/cinema/datetime',
                    data: 'id='+val1+'&val2='+vla2+'&val3='+val3,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                            $("#loading").show();
            alert(id);
                    },
                    success:  function(response) {
        if(response.type == "success"){
           alert(response);
                $("#time").html(response);
            }
        }   });
}); });
```

[The response gotten from the server, that success function doesn't read.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmqeZ.png)

Comment: It looks like you're getting HTML back from the server, rather than JSON

Comment: Try "console.log(response);" inside the success function. That will help you know what type of response you are receiving from the server. Accordingly, you can adjust your further code.

Comment: Also, typo in your code: vla2

Comment: No type in it changed the parameters here. Did a console.log(response) nothing came up

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!... i changed this

```
success: function (response) {
    if (response.type == "success") {
        alert(response);
        $("#time").html(response);
    }
}
```

into this

```
success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
        $("#time").html(response);
}
```

also changed my dataType into html

Answer (score 0):

change method from get to post and data as following

```
    data: {'id':val1,'val2':vla2,'val3':val3},
```

or just replace following code,

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $("#date").change(function(event) {
        var val1= document.getElementById('val1').value;
        var val2= document.getElementById('val2').value;
        var val3= document.getElementById('val3').value;

                $.ajax({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://localhost/cinema/datetime',
                        data: {'id':val1,'val2':vla2,'val3':val3},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false,
                        beforeSend: function() {
                                $("#loading").show();
                alert(id);
                        },
                        success:  function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success"){
               alert(response);
                    $("#time").html(response);
                }
            }   });
    }); });
```